# Can the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix be a Vandermonde matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, inverse

Recall that a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) is a matrix of the form

$$V(\vec x)=V(x_0,...,x_n):=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & & \vdots &\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^n \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

for numbers $x_0,...,x_n\in\Bbb C$, and that $V(\vec x)$ is invertible if and only if the $x_i$ are distinct.

I am interested in the case when the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix is again a Vandermonde matrix, or $V(\vec x)V(\vec y)=\mathrm{Id}$. Comparing number of variables ($=2(n+1)$) with number of constraints ($=(n+1)^2$) we should not expect there to be solutions, except for $n\in\{0,1\}$.

Here is a solution for $n=1$: $\vec x=\vec y=(0,-1)$, or

$$V(\vec x)=V(\vec y)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \phantom+0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

> **Question:** Can the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix be a Vandermonde matrix for $n\ge 2$?